# Shapiro-Wilk test

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, I want to calculate the [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) value of my selected data.

Apparently, the function DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.normal_dist_fit is able to do it, but it takes a table name as a parameter, and not the result of a select.

The values I am working with are numbers, selected after many inner joins. Here is a sample of my values for a typical test (each value are only one number, I only regrouped them here for readability) :

```
-1,1168954372406006 -1,0339429378509521 -1,0194162130355835 -,9636680483818054 -,9536418914794922 -,9111286401748657 -,851311981678009 -,8325300216674805 -,8051750063896179 -,738100528717041 -,7174761295318604 -,6651638746261597 -,663613498210907 -,6444216966629028 -,6267942190170288 -,6180349588394165 -,6027824282646179 -,5999149084091187 -,5908389687538147 -,590206503868103 -,5845686793327332 -,5831132531166077 -,5629676580429077 -,5572993159294128 -,5481508374214172 -,5445670485496521 -,5093156099319458 -,49224603176116943 -,47992199659347534 -,4758097231388092 -,4546264410018921 -,38799363374710083 -,3803306519985199 -,3734436631202698 -,36905646324157715 -,27978914976119995 -,2048187553882599 -,16521787643432617
```

Comment: is it an option to create a temporary table, and each time before calculating the value, deleting from it and inserting into it the values of the select? Then you could use the table as parameter

Comment: I would rather not create tables on the company servers, but if it is possible to do it on the client side that would be a solution. I'm not sure on how to implement it, if it is even possible...

Comment: Anything that can take a table as an argument can also take the result of a SELECT query as the same argument. If your SELECT statement is <SELECT...> then you can wrap it within a WITH clause: WITH MY_RESULT AS <SELECT...> and then immediately follow this with the query to compute the Shapiro-Wilk value, using MY_RESULT as the name of the table. Oracle doesn't care if it's a table or a named subquery (as it is with the WITH clause).

Comment: @mathguy Depends what you mean by "table". [dbms_stat_funcs.normal_dist_fit](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stat_f.htm#ARPLS68476) takes owner, table name and column parameters. From 18c, [private temporary tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c) might help although you would still need `create table` privilege.

Comment: @mathguy I can't get your solution to work :  WITH ... AS just doesn't seem to be made for this. 

"WITH MY_RESULT AS (...) DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.normal_dist_fit(...)" returns an error "ORA-00928: error missing SELECT keyword". As I understand it, It is only intended for a query usage

Comment: Hm... OK, I didn't realize the normality test is a *procedure* rather than function (in a package that has **FUNCS** in its name, no less). There is no reason for that - it should be a function - but that's not my decision to make. OK, so it's a procedure. Are you allowed to create **views** in your schema? If you are, then you can create a view: `create view my_view(my_col) as SELECT ...` (and put your query after `SELECT`). Then call the procedure on this view instead of a table. Views are just saved queries, so if you don't have the needed privileges, asked that they be granted to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view based on your query. ("View" just means a named query, whose code is saved for future use; a view does not contain any data. So even if you would rather not create tables on a production server, it may be OK to create views.) Then you can use this view in a call to the goodness-of-fit procedure.

First let's clarify that `DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.normal_dist_fit` is not a function, as might be suggested by the FUNCS in the package name (and as you say in your post), but a **procedure**. In fact, **all** the subprograms in that package are procedures!

The documentation for the package is **wrong**.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stat_f.htm#ARPLS68476

It says that `mean` and `stddev` are **IN** parameters. They are not; they are **OUT** parameters. It is not really clear why they are needed in this procedure (there are separate functions to compute them), but again, that is not my choice, it's Oracle's.

Here is a brief example of using the `normal_dist_fit` procedure on a physical table (from a different schema: the standard `HR` schema). Note that I must have the `select any table` privilege, or some other privilege that allows me to select from tables in the `HR` schema. (I am not logged in as `HR`, but as another user, `MATHGUY`.)

```
declare
  mn number;
  sd number;
  sw number;
begin
  dbms_stat_funcs.normal_dist_fit('HR', 'EMPLOYEES', 'SALARY',
                                  'SHAPIRO_WILKS', mn, sd, sw);
end;
/

W value : .8739562109117848523112862359519603805821

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

(Note that the argument for the Shapiro-Wilk test is **'SHAPIRO_WILKS'**, with an **S** at the end; perhaps Oracle had a good reason for this, although I doubt it.)

Now, let's say in **my** schema I have this query, which produces a column of numbers:

```
select salary * (1 + nvl(commission_pct, 0)) as total_compensation 
from   hr.employees
;
```

This computes total compensation, including commission (for those employees who have one; the `NVL` call is needed because for employees without a commission, the percentage is shown as NULL rather than zero).

I will create a **view** based on this query... but I will need to have the needed privileges, and there is just a slight complication.

So far I assumed I can select from a table in the `HR` schema; indeed, I have the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege. But, in my case, I have that privilege *through a role*. That's OK for selecting, but not OK for creating a view based on that `SELECT`. To create a view, I must have `SELECT ANY TABLE` (or a much weaker grant: to select specifically from that one table, or perhaps restricted even further to just the two columns I need) **granted to me directly**, not through a role. This is something you need to discuss with your DBA; it's a privilege you already have (otherwise your existing `SELECT` wouldn't work), but if you have it through a role, now you will need to have it granted directly to you. And, of course, you must have the `CREATE VIEW` privilege.

OK, so suppose you have the right privileges. Then you can do this:

**Create the view**

```
create or replace view my_emp(total_comp) 
as 
    select salary*(1 + nvl(commission_pct, 0)) from hr.employees;
```

**Invoke the procedure**

```
declare
  mn number;
  sd number;
  sw number;
begin
  dbms_stat_funcs.normal_dist_fit('MATHGUY', 'MY_EMP', 'TOTAL_COMP', 
                                  'SHAPIRO_WILKS', mn, sd, sw);
end;
/

W value : .8852586932906502861798487994791857389177
```

Comment: This sound great. Clear answer.

Sadly my problem evolved, a single query approach has been chosen, the results being stored into arrays after iterating through the query result. I'll have to change the main query and investigate dynamic views for this to work. In the meanwhile the non-optimal temp table method will do the work.